# push_back and exception safety

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that push_back can throw a bad_alloc exception and if there is no try catch block it is not true that the destructors are called.
if any push_back throws and it's not inside a try catch block I'll have a memory leak?  This means that if I don't want to have a leak I have to wrap every push_back inside a try catch?Is this behaviour too rare and expensive for a vector not to catch the exception, release the already allocated memory and rethrow the exception?

Comment: please show an example ([mcve]). It isnt completely clear what you mean. You don't need a try-catch block to get destructors called.

Comment: If a `bad_alloc` is called your best course of action is to crash. Don't try to handle the error. If you're on a critical system that can't crash then you need to take preemptive care to not run out of memory.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what a memory leak is. It's memory that is not freed by a program that keeps running. If the program ends or crashes there is no leak since the program is not running anymore. If the exception is catched you should be able to handle things gracefully anyway, or terminate.

Comment: @super I understand by memory leak that if I make new and not its corresponding delete this is a memory leak.

Comment: @super Another point is that you trust your operating system to free up that memory for you, at which point I have nothing to say.

Comment: @sos Yes, the new/delete part is correct. I don't really see how/why the distinction is relevant though. Talking about a memory leak in a program that's not running makes no sense.

Comment: @sos: Other resources might need to be cleaned in addition to memory.

Comment: @Jarod42 Right, for example a file descriptor, I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if there is no try catch block it is not true that the destructors are called

It's [implementation-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) whether stack unwinding (which calls destructors) happens in this case or not.

> if any push_back throws and it's not inside a try catch block I'll have a memory leak?

It doesn't really matter, because all memory allocated by your program is freed when the program exits or crashes. All files opened by your program are automatically closed, and so on.

If, for some reason, you must do something else when the program exits or crashes, then yes, you can't rely solely on a destructor.

Rather than putting the entire contents of `main` in a `try`/`catch`, you might want to use `std::set_terminate`, or something similar.

Comment: If I make a few push_back calls and an exception occurs in some of them, the memory that has already been allocated by the vector is released?

Comment: @sos If your program crashes due to an unhandled exception, then all memory you allocated is freed, regardless of destructors. If it doesn't crash (i.e. you catch the exceptions), proper destructors are called and free the memory.

Comment: @HoyBlackCat  it's platform defined, not all embedded platforms follow that rule and require warm reset of user space or whole kernel space. For those platform knowing if it's happening or not is essential and sadly some consumer-class run-time libraries and frameworks (e.g. Qt as opposed to OSG) do not comply with that. I personally worked witha  platform used for teller terminals which  couldn't implement Qt-based GUI for kiosk mode because of possible memory leaks happening. Even normal termination of process was leaving memory allocated.

Answer (score 1):

In theory if `push_back` throws, memory is not allocated by the container itself.

If you allocate memory on your own, you should wrap your allocations into smart pointers, so that they safely deallocate in this case. This means, instead of this:

```
v.push_back(new Obj{});
```

have this:

```
v.push_back(std::make_unique<Obj>())
```

So assuming you have some upper level handling of `std::bad_alloc` exception (or any `std::exception`), you can recover without memory leaks, and you don't need to wrap every allocation with `try`/`catch`.

---

In practice, many programs don't handle memory allocation failure properly, especially for small allocations. It takes too much effort to make it all correctly

And in some cases you don't even get bad_alloc on allocation, you just get hard page fault on trying to use that memory.